Moving average in Looker Studio
I'm completely frustrated while not being to solve this extremely straightforward-sounding issue with all of the modern AI tools we have on place.
Anyways. I have a dataset loaded in Looker Studio which has a date column called "posting_date" and a sales column called "amount". I have plotted in my multi chart the posting_date column on year-month format as dimension and then the amount in the measure.
Our business is very seasonal and therefore we always us rolling-12-month averages in sales analysis.
Question: how on earth am I able to put R12M line chart on top of the monthly sales amounts which is currently as a barchart visualized?
All help is very appreciated!

This question is similar to: Running Average in Google Data Studio. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The best hint I can give you so far
1- Create a new calculated metric field in your dataset for the rolling 12 month average in sales.
2- Add the new metric as a line to you current bar chart.
Best,
